# Which property of jQuery datatable-settings object shows whether "pagination" of datatable is true or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables, settings

Here is the code:

```
var $oTable = $('#table').DataTable( {"bPaginate" : true}; );

The following piece of code returns the settings object"
$oTable.settings()[0]
```

Now, I need to know the property of the settings object that signifies whether "pagination" is true or false. Here is the image that shows the settings object in browser console:

[image: Image that shows the settings object of datatable]

Answer (score 0):

**bPaginate** **bServerSide** under oFeatures and oInit

[console log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhmoD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Searching on [jquery.dataTables.js 1.9.4](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js) I do not see any property for that, I think you will have to do something similar to a function of this version:

```
    function _fnCalculateEnd( oSettings )
    {
        if ( oSettings.oFeatures.bPaginate === false )
        {
            oSettings._iDisplayEnd = oSettings.aiDisplay.length;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Set the end point of the display - based on how many elements there are
             * still to display
             */
            if ( oSettings._iDisplayStart + oSettings._iDisplayLength > oSettings.aiDisplay.length ||
                   oSettings._iDisplayLength == -1 )
            {
                oSettings._iDisplayEnd = oSettings.aiDisplay.length;
            }
            else
            {
                oSettings._iDisplayEnd = oSettings._iDisplayStart + oSettings._iDisplayLength;
            }
        }
    }
```

So you have to know if there is pagination looking at *_iDisplayStart* and *_iDisplayLength* (base + offset) and the length of the array of results *aiDisplay*.